# How are vertex capacities defined in a flow network?

Tags: linear-programming, network-flow

I'm new to network flows and I'm reading this topic from Cormen's Algorithms book (3rd edition) from 26 chapter. I came across this problem from the 26.1 section

> Suppose that, in addition to edge capacities, a flow network has
> vertex capacities. That is each vertex  has a limit $l$ on how much
> flow can pass though . Show how to transform a flow network $G = (V, E)$ with vertex capacities into an equivalent flow network $G' = (V', E')$ without vertex capacities, such that a maximum flow in $G'$ has the
> same value as a maximum flow in $G$.

I want to understand how the author has defined vertex capacities here? Because from my understanding, the most general definition would be

$l(v) = \sum\limits_{e \text{ into } v} f(v) - \sum\limits_{e \text{ out of } v} f(v)$

but if this is so, then for all $v$ not in the set of source and sink nodes,

$l(v)= 0$, so we are never really setting any limit. Please help me understand the vertex capacity term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like edges have capacities on them (i.e, how much flow is allowed to go through them), they have added capacities for nodes.

If a node $v$ has capacity $C_v$, then any flow with $\sum_{e \text{ into } v} f(e)>C_v$ is considered *invalid* (it violates the node capacity rule).

Comment: So, we are putting an upper bound on the flow that can go into a vertex when we talk about network capacity. Would that be correct interpretation?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Intuitively it is the same definition like for capacity in edges.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying it for me. I'm unable to upvote because I don't have the necessary reputation. Thank you so much.